# Removed python2.7, python2 python3, python3.4 from /usr/bin/

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, python3

I was tinkering with my computer yesterday and, unaware of the importance of /usr/bin/, promptly removed all of the python files from there, and then proceeded to get rid of all the packages that depended on them for some reason.

Smart, I know.

After quite a few hours today, I managed to recover nearly everything, however, the only thing that won't budge is python3. Whenever I try to reinstall I get a message of the sort:

```
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

- `py3clean` and `py3compile` should be in `python3-minimal`. Try to install it first:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python3-minimal
  ```

Update question if you get any error.

Comment: I had already installed python3-minimal, but it still wouldn't budge.
I ended up removing everything I'd installed and got the same error, this time with pycompile and pyclean. I tried doing that a few times but it'd alternate between python-minimal and python3-minimal giving me problems. When that wouldn't work, I rebooted the computer and for some reason everything managed to install correctly.